# Run custom preprocessing step for source files in Xcode build

Tags: xcode

As part of my build process (in Visual Studio), I use a custom MSBuild task that takes all the input source files, copies them to a secondary location, runs a preprocessing tool over them, and then gives the copies back to MSBuild to continue the build process with. I'm now working on a project for iOS, and I need to be able to do the same thing. It's been a very long time since I've worked with Xcode, so I'm pretty rusty on how I can set up the build process to work the same way I just described.

Specifically, here's the preprocessing that I'm doing:

As with many games and engines, there are often a lot of named resources, events, script symbols, object states, etc. that need to be human readable when represented in source code but for which having to do a full string comparison at runtime would be much too costly. Instead of using a full string, I use a 32-bit `StringId` integer type to represent these values. My preprocessing tool runs through the source code and replaces all instances of a macro in the form `SID('some-named-identifier')` with the 32-bit hash of the string inside that macro. During development, programmers and designers can use arbitrary strings as identifiers for whatever they need to be used for. At runtime, comparisons between `StringId`s are simple integer comparisons and since they are the hashed versions of the actual strings, there are no strings stored in the compiled binary that could be extracted.

Additionally, when preprocessing the `SID` macros, I populate a MySQL database with the strings and their hashed values. This lets me do a reverse lookup at runtime in order to print the human-readable strings while debugging. It's a great system, and I'd love to get it working in Xcode as well!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you mean sqlite instead of mysql?

Comment: No? And how is that even relevant to the question?

Comment: I was just surprised by the use of MySQL which must be running external to the device; I would have thought sqlite was better for this. Does this technique save much in terms of performance?  I wouldn't have thought so, given the overhead of a MySQL query. Anyway to answer your question, to some extent, you have to create a script to pre-process each source file and then output the processed files to the *DerivedData* directory for compilation.  This sounds like a lot of hassle and won't be trivial to set-up.

Comment: The database is only to convert StringIds to their string representations during development. The database does not live on the device, as it's also queried by the debugger in order to display strings instead of the integer representation while program execution is stopped. Additionally, multiple developers will be adding to it constantly, so having it in an external location is necessary.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?